# how to create dinamic port in golang (echo framwork)

Tags: go, go-echo

i have package config.go in this my code

```
package config
import (
    "fmt"
    logger "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)
func DatabaseConnect() *gorm.DB {
DBURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s", pkg.GodotEnv("DB_HOST"), pkg.GodotEnv("DB_PORT"), pkg.GodotEnv("DB_USER"), pkg.GodotEnv("DB_NAME"), pkg.GodotEnv("DB_PASSWORD"))

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(DBURL), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        defer logger.Info("Database connection failed")
        logger.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    return db
}
```

and main.go

```
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    db := config.DatabaseConnect()
    middleware.WebSecurityConfig(e)
    routes.NewRoute(db, e)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}
```

I want to create a dynamic routing like the example below :

```
server.Initialize(os.Getenv("DB_DRIVER"), os.Getenv("DB_USER"), os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("DB_PORT"), os.Getenv("DB_HOST"), os.Getenv("DB_NAME")) 

server.Run(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"))
```

how to create dinamic port server ? thanks

Comment: `e.Start(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"))`? Your question would be easier to answer if you explained what `server` is (this appears in the last bit of code but is never defined). Perhaps show what you have tried (do you just want a `struct` with `Initialize` and `Run` methods?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: https://github.com/joho/godotenv.

Add your application configuration to your .env file in the root of your project:

```
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_USER=root
...
```

Then in your Go app you can do something like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
  err := godotenv.Load()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
  }

  driver:= os.Getenv("DB_DRIVER")
  user:= os.Getenv("DB_USER")
  // todo

}
```